# contract runner does not support sending transactions

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, hardhat

Update (08 July 2023) : From `node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js`, I found the error message (the `assert` part).

```js
 const send = async function (...args) {
        const runner = contract.runner;
        assert(canSend(runner), "contract runner does not support sending transactions", "UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION", { operation: "sendTransaction" });
        const tx = await runner.sendTransaction(await populateTransaction(...args));
        const provider = getProvider(contract.runner);
        // @TODO: the provider can be null; make a custom dummy provider that will throw a
        // meaningful error
        return new ContractTransactionResponse(contract.interface, provider, tx);
    };
```

And the `canSend` is:

```js
function canSend(value) {
    return (value && typeof (value.sendTransaction) === "function");
}
```

So basically, `contract.runner` should be a function type. However, in my case, `contract.runner` is a string (address type).

Even more strange thing is that I put a console.log right before execute a smart contract function whether the runner has function or not. `console.log('myContract.runner.sendTransaction :', myContract.runner.sendTransaction);` This properly prints a function.

I am not sure where & why `contract.runner` is a string. Anyone knows the reason?

---

The original post:
I am facing an error `error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.0)`  when I execute `pay()` from Frontend.
I am not sure where to start debugging.
It's running on my local with hardhat and Metamask.

```typescript
const setContracts = async () => { // #1. I run this first.
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
  const signer = await provider.getSigner();
  const myContract: ethers.Contract = new ethers.Contract(myContractAddress, contractABI, 
  signer);

  setMyContract(myContract);
}

const pay = async() => { // #2. then run this one 
    const amount = ethers.parseUnits("1.0", 18);
    console.log('myContract.runner.sendTransaction :', myContract.runner.sendTransaction); // <- function properly printed
    myContract
      .connect(connectedAccount) // #3. This account has 1,000 ETH
      .donate(targetAddress, {value: amount});  // #4. error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.0)
 
  };
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137839/error-contract-runner-does-not-support-calling-operation-call-code-unsuppor/76540964#76540964

Comment: This should solve the issue

Comment: @ZartajAfser Thanks for the comment but I am already using "signer" when I get an instance of the contract and not provider.

Comment: Did you check if the signer, provider, and contract everything is initialized correctly, by console logging them?

Comment: @ZartajAfser I believe yes and even some transaction which update storage variable work. Only sending ETH not working for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `.connect(connectedAccount)` when I removed this code, the `runner` object contains `sendTransaction`.